# Adding a subscription to more than one product

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

is it possible to add a subscription to multiple products? I have a scenario where I have multiple customers using subscription keys and want to give Customer A access to Product A and B but Customer B access to Product B and C.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in the Product-Page:

Azure Portal -> API Management -> Products

Select "Product A"

-> Subscriptions
==> "Add Subscribers"

Comment: Hi, that would seem the obvious answer but when I click "Add Subscribers" I get and "Add Users" window appear. If I click "Add Subscription" a window appears to create a new subscription.

Comment: "Add subscribers" - add multiple subscriptions at once, that's why you're asked to select multiple users. "Add subscription" - add single subscription.

Comment: User can have subscriptions to many products, although they must be added one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are talking about API. Yes you can add several subscriptions to same product.[Sample_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvFrR.png)

Comment: Welcome Nomad, great to have you on-board. Could you include example code rather than just a link. Links tend to go stale over time.

Comment: Thanks @AlexStephens. This is an image, captured from Azure portal.

Comment: @nomad... clicking on that button opens a New Subscription button (for me at least). It doesn't allow me to select existing subs.

Comment: @nomad, try adding the actual screenshot as an image to the post, this will greatly help others and give you more chance of being marked as the correct answer.

Comment: @AlexStephens This is actual screenshot from my azure account. But all the information can't shared here. That is why i cropped the image.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question and answer, but I didn't find what I was looking for when I searched for this, so here goes my findings:

API Management has support for Access Groups. A product can set an access group under access control. This will make it so only users that are members of this group can see it in ApiManagement. Doing this, you can create just a single subscription for all API's, and filter using access policies, to verify that you can only use the API's that you are allowed to, due to the access groups.

I used the following policy on my API's to make sure the user has access, together with an AllApis subscription:

```
 <choose>
        <when condition="@(context?.User?.Groups == null || !(context.User.Groups.Any(q => q.Id == context?.Api?.Id)))">
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized" />
                <set-header name="WWW-Authenticate" exists-action="override">
                    <value>Unauthorized. Subscription key not valid for this API."</value>
                </set-header>
            </return-response>
        </when>
    </choose>
```

All in all, this ends up with customizable access to API's, using only a single subscription key. You can choose any permutation of users and API accesses.

This can end up fulfilling your desired outcome, of having a single key that Customer 1 uses for both API A and B, while customer 2 uses a single key for both B and C.